# Programmatically compile java with JavaCompiler?

Tags: java, java-compiler-api

I got this Java code from another Stack Overflow thread

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    String source = " public class Test { public static void main(String args[]) {     System.out.println(\"hello\"); } }";

    // Save source in .java file.
    File root = new File("C:\\java\\");
    root.mkdir();
    File sourceFile = new File(root, "\\Test.java");
    Writer writer = new FileWriter(sourceFile);
    writer.write(source);
    writer.close();

    // Compile source file.
    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
    compiler.run(null, null, null, sourceFile.getPath());
  }
}
```

But I keep getting a NullPointerException like this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.zove.compiler.Main.main(Main.java:24)
```

It *does* compile but it throws the exception at runtime.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which line is `Main.java:24`? Is `ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()` returning null?

Comment: Given the code is only 21 lines long, I cannot see how the NPE could occur at line 24.  Is it your intention to waste the time of people trying to help you?  What code are you **actually** using?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Can you take a look on this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36583278/how-can-compile-i-java-file-in-jsp

Answer (score 5):

Your code works fine for me when I execute it using the JDK. If I execute it using the JRE I get a NullPointerException on `compiler.run(...)` like you.

Therefore I assume that you only have to switch the Java runtime for executing your code.

Answer (score 3):

Well you can't compile java programs using the JRE.

So you have to have the **JDK** in your path so that the compilation be possible.

In your case without even running your program if you run in command line:
`javac` you would get

> 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command

This is why you get the null pointer exception.