# Compiled Java compiler in JAR form?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, jar

I have an application which requires compiling a .java file into a .class file ***within the application***.  Ideally, I'd like to have a JAR that I could use its api to compile by giving two arguments: the name of the file to be compiled and the directory to store the .class file.  My application will use the Java compiler, which will be packaged and shipped with the software.

I actually have a small java compiler like I describe in JAR form, but it only has a subset of what java 7.0 has.

Is the java compiler available in Jar form like this?

Comment: "I have an application which requires compiling a .java file into a .class file within the application." -- I have to ask what on earth this is for - 99 times out of 100 SO questions involving this are bad design rather than, say, development on a compiler, lint collector, IDE, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Java Compiler API (JSR 199)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=199) was created for this purpose, you create a compiler instance like this:

`JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();`

Here is a good educational tutorial on [Generating Java classes dynamically](http://www.accordess.com/wpblog/an-overview-of-java-compilation-api-jsr-199/)

and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665809/programmatically-compile-java-with-javacompiler) is a related question with example code

Answer (score 3):

the compiler is in tools.jar.

refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/package-summary.html